# Newbie Installation Help: Calico CLI - Windows

Tags: command-line, installation, command-line-interface, calico

hopefully this is rookie and easy question. I'm trying to install CLI on my local Windows machine to modify a hosted Kubernetes server.

Upon downloading [basic Windows Installer](https://github.com/projectcalico/calicoctl/releases/tag/v1.6.1) from their Github, I cannot seem to run successfully to install. A command line opens for a brief second, disappears and nothing happened.

I've tried on two different Windows PCs (Win10 and Win7), both with admin priv and run as admin used. I've tried to download the source code and see calicotcl\commands folder where it has the resources as .go that I am looking to utilize. I've tried calling those directly from CMD line with no luck but I'm pretty green in this world.

I've spent two days trying to get past this one step... any help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the downloaded package is not a installer, it's a portable command line tool. I have downloaded the calicoctl v3.1.3, then i can run it in cmd.exe, see the picture here:[run calicoctl in command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cD00.png)

Answer (score 0):

The binary available there is not an installer but the binary itself. If you open a terminal and run that binary and pass `version` to it you should see the version information printed out (just as an example to check that it is run-able).

Check out the docs to [configure access to Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.6/reference/calicoctl/setup/) for the calicoctl command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, might need a last bit of hand holding if your up to it :) So I downloaded calicoctl from the site:

https://docs.projectcalico.org/master/releases/

Now I have a single file on my C:\. When I open terminal, cd to directory and run file - nada, is not recognized as an internal or external command.